# How can I make this simple C# generics factory work?

Tags: c#, generics, factories

I have this design:

```
public interface IFactory<T> {
  T Create();
  T CreateWithSensibleDefaults();
}

public class AppleFactory : IFactory<Apple> { ... }
public class BananaFactory : IFactory<Banana> { ... }
// ...
```

The fictitious `Apple` and `Banana` here do not necessarily share any common types (other than `object`, of course).

I don't want clients to have to depend on specific factories, so instead, you can just ask a `FactoryManager` for a new type. It has a `FactoryForType` method:

```
IFactory<T> FactoryForType<T>();
```

Now you can invoke the appropriate interface methods with something like `FactoryForType<Apple>().Create()`. So far, so good.

But there's a problem at the implementation level: how do I store this mapping from types to `IFactory<T>`s? The naive answer is an `IDictionary<Type, IFactory<T>>`, but that doesn't work since there's no type covariance on the `T` (I'm using C# 3.5). Am I just stuck with an `IDictionary<Type, object>` and doing the casting manually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately yes you are stuck with the manual casting.  However this casting can be an implementation detail and not seen by the consumer.  For example

```
public class FactoryMap { 
  private Dictionary<Type,object> _map = new Dictionary<Type,object>();
  public void Add<T>(IFactory<T> factory) {
    _map[typeof(T)] = factory;
  }
  public IFactory<T> Get<T>() {
    return (IFactory<T>)_map[typeof(T)];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's about what I have now; I figured there wasn't much wiggle room with access to covariance.